# subplots in reverse order

Tags: python, matplotlib

The subplots I am taking are in reverse order.

```
legend=('data','fit')
mycolor=('b-','r-')
y_label=('4th','5th')

for i in range(2):
    for label,color in zip(legend,mycolor):
        plt.subplot(1,2,i)
        plt.plot(x,y,'mo',smooth_x,np.polyval(np.polyfit(x,y,i+4),smooth_x),mycolor[i])
        plt.legend(legend)
        plt.ylabel(y_label[i])

plt.title('Orders')    
plt.show()
```

I am taking at the left side(the first subplot) the 5th order plot and at the right side(the second subplot) the 4th order.
But I have   `y_label=('4th','5th')` .

Note that the plots are correct.The problem is only that they appear in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(2)` is the list `[0, 1]`:

```
>>> range(2)
[0, 1]
```

while `supblot(1,2,i)` expects `i` to be either `1` or `2`.

You should use `subplot(1,2,i+1)`.

Comment: :Excellent!Thanks a lot!I didn't thought the subplot number!